# Python-Integrate then save text file

Tags: python, numpy

To all:

This question pertains to some MS research I am doing.

What I want to do is seemingly simple. I have a text file of values( time, .....values). I then want to integrate from 0 to those values for all times, then save that value to a text file.

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import os, sys, shutil
import math

#######################

#Load Data
data = loadtxt('wh.txt')

#Open file to save plots to
shutil.rmtree("wh_files")
os.makedirs("wh_files")
os.chdir("wh_files")

for i in range(0,100,1):
   int = trapz(data[i,:],axis=0)
   print int
   savetxt('int.txt', int)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
  File "integral.py", line 19, in 
    savetxt('int.txt', int)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 960, in savetxt
    ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days on an off now, but am yet to find a solution. I appreciate any help/comments you can give.

Comment: In `int = trapz(data[i,:],axis=0)` did you mean to have `data[i:]` instead of `data[i,:]`?

Comment: Also, having a variable named like one of the standard types (`int`) is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `int` is a float but `savetxt` requires an array. You want to create a numpy array for all the integration results, then save it at the end using `savetxt`. I think something like this should do the trick:

```
int_array = apply_along_axis(trapz, 0, data)
savetxt('int.txt', int_array)
```

Keep in mind that this (along with your original example) will sum the time fields, rather than integrating across time. This will only yield valid results if the spacing along the x-axis is 1. Otherwise you'll want to do something like this:

```
t = data[0,:]
int_array = apply_along_axis(trapz, 0, data[1:,:], t)
savetxt('int.txt', int_array)
```

Assuming the time fields are numeric.

**edit**: Further explanation of 2nd code section follows.

You're using the trapezoidal rule to integrate a variety of values, which is an integration approximation technique that works by summing the average of successive y-values on a curve multiplied by the change in x between the two y-values. This amounts to calculating the area of a trapezoid that connects the two y-values and the x-axis, like so:

[image: Trapezoid Rule]

It's not completely clear from your question, but it seemed that you were integrating the values across time, so that the x-axis would represent time. The x-values need to be incorporated to get the correct area of each trapezoid (the area of each trapezoid is (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>) * (y<sub>2</sub> + y<sub>1</sub>) / 2 and the final integration result is the sum of all such areas).

The simplest way to incorporate these x-axis values is to pass it into the `trapz` function as the `x` parameter (see the [docstring](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#head-c33a118315b4eb8d12aa4c10b0371b8d893f0927)). In the example above, I used `t = data[0,:]` as the array of x values suchly.

Another caveat: if all spacing between x values are the same (so that x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub> is a constant), you can save yourself some calculation by pulling this out of the summation and simply multiplying it at the end. This functionality is available through the `trapz` function with the `dx` parameter. So, if you're time measurements were taken every 30 seconds, for example, you could replace the 2nd line in my 2nd example with:

```
int_array = apply_along_axis(trapz, 0, data[1:,:], None, 30)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the advice. Will, can you explain the last bit of code you wrote? I am not sure what you mean. @Will

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I did not do a good job asking my question. I am fact only integrating the volume for each time not with respect to time. i.e. to 1.0s I have a series of values that represent a water surface height, then for 1.5s I have a new series of values have represent a new surface configuration. I am taking those values then seeing how thy change over throughout time. I really appreciate the time you took in answering this question.