# Printing out list of values

Tags: python, printing, ctypes

I have a C library that i wraped in Python with ctypes and I have this DLL below
that prints out the time values when i ask it to. But rather than going through
each item and manually asking it to print out each value 60000 times. I want it to create its own list with all of the values
Here is a small example of my code and the library that i have wrapped:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

class SParm(Structure):
pass

SParm._fields_ = [
        ('name', ctypes.c_char_p),
        ('data', ctypes.POINTER(ParmData)),
        ('time', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))]

MultiF = (b'path_to_file')   
dll = CDLL('path_to_dll') 

PN = ctypes.c_char_p(b'Paramter_name')
startTime = ctypes.c_double(-3.4**38)
stopTime = ctypes.c_double(3.4**38)
DT_RETURN = 0x0100
DT_FLOAT = 0x0001
convertType = (DT_RETURNGMT|DT_FLOAT)
Null = 0

dll.readSParm.argtypes = (POINTER(SFile), c_char_p, c_double, c_double, c_double, POINTER(TTag), c_ushort,)   
dll.readSParm.restype = POINTER(SParm)

g = dll.readSParm(f, PN, startTime, stopTime, Null, None, convertType)

print(g[0].time[0])
print(g[0].time[1])
print(g[0].time[51999])
```

these are the return values that the code give me:

```
-1031.0762939453125
-1031.0362548828125
0.0
```

Instead of manually asking it to print out each individual value 51000 times and then manually putting all  those values into a list. I want something that will print out all of the values at once. Is there a code that can do this?
maybe print() isn't the best way to get all of the values into a list.

**My question is this:**
 How can I print all of the values contained in

```
(g[0].time)
```

without manually asking it to individually print out the values and put them into a list?

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
import numpy as np
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, g[0].time)
```

Comment: @DamianLattenero Thanks! `savetxt()` has a couple of advantages such as it will work for multi-column arrays as well.

Comment: In this example what is a?

Comment: Disregard that last comment. when I run this is get  `ncol = X.shape[1] IndexError: tuple index out of range` error

Comment: @eliza.b I cannot reproduce your error. You are probably passing a wrong value to the `savetxt()` function such as an integer instead of a list/array - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930671/python-integrate-then-save-text-file

Comment: I have also edited my answer to replace `a` explicitly with `g[0].time` so that there should not be any confusion over what `a` is.

Answer (score 3):

You could join them

```
print('\n'.join(g[0].time))
```

This will create one large string separating each value with the new line.

Comment: there is a `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` with this line the arrow points to the ) right after the word time.

Comment: I was missing the last parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with a simple for loop:

```
for x in g[0].time:
  print(g[0].time[x])
```

Comment: shouldn't print x ?

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska Positive! I will correct it, iuf, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can print them as one list, doing:

```
print(g[0].time)
```

Or print every value separately:

```
for value in g[0].time:
    print(value)
```